# Node.js event loop blocked for no apparent reason

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/blocked to check to see whether the event loop is being blocked.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
require('dotenv').config();
var blocked = require('blocked');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var cassandradriver = require('cassandra-driver');
var timeuuid = require('cassandra-driver').types.TimeUuid;
var redis = require('redis');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 50,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: process.env.username,
    password: process.env.password,
    database: 'database1',
    charset: 'utf8mb4'
});

var authProvider = new cassandradriver.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider('username', 'password');
var cassclient = new cassandradriver.Client({
    contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1:9042'],
    keyspace: 'test',
    authProvider: authProvider
});

var redisdb = redis.createClient({
    password: 'password'
});

var redisdb1 = redis.createClient({
    password: 'password'
});
redisdb1.select(1);

var redisdb2 = redis.createClient({
    password: 'password'
});
redisdb2.select(2);

blocked(function(ms){
  console.log('BLOCKED FOR %sms', ms | 0);
});
```

If I leave this code running, I see the following in the console (maybe about 1 minute between each):

```
BLOCKED FOR 12ms
BLOCKED FOR 10ms
BLOCKED FOR 18ms
BLOCKED FOR 10ms
BLOCKED FOR 14ms
```

If I leave it running, I get a message every 1-2 seconds saying that the event loop is blocked. It all varies between 10-25 ms.

Is there a reason why this is happening? I'm not even querying MySQL, Cassandra or redis for anything and the event loop is being blocked.

If I'm misunderstanding the `blocked` package please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could be keepalive messages being transmitted and parsed across each database connection. I think triggering the callback at >=10ms is way too low to start being concerned about blocked event loops.

Comment: I see. What would you say is an appropriate amount of milliseconds to be concerned about blocked event loops? 50?